# How to plot variables that only contains true value

Tags: python

```
fig, ax =plt.subplots(1,5,figsize=(25,5))
sns.countplot(x='Foraging',data=df,palette='Pastel1',ax=ax[0])
sns.countplot(x='Eating',data=df,palette='Pastel1',ax=ax[1])
sns.countplot(x='Climbing',data=df,palette='Pastel1',ax=ax[2])
sns.countplot(x='Chasing',data=df,palette='Pastel1',ax=ax[3])
sns.countplot(x='Running',data=df,palette='Pastel1',ax=ax[4])
fig.show()
```

How can I plot a variable that only contains `'true'`?

I've tried
`df['Foraging']=df['Foraging']==1`
**but it is not working**

Answer (score 0):

You could use the loc method to select rows where the Foraging column is equal to true and then plot the resulting dataframe:

```
# Select rows where 'Foraging' is 'true'
foraging_df = df.loc[df['Foraging'] == 'true']

# Plot the count of 'Foraging'
sns.countplot(x='Foraging', data=foraging_df, palette='Pastel1')
```

Alternatively, you can use the query method to filter the dataframe using a boolean expression:

```
# Select rows where 'Foraging' is 'true'
foraging_df = df.query('Foraging == "true"')

# Plot the count of 'Foraging'
sns.countplot(x='Foraging', data=foraging_df, palette='Pastel1')
```

Comment: i got a error min() arg is an empty sequence

Comment: fig, ax =plt.subplots(1,5,figsize=(25,5))
sns.countplot(x='Foraging',data=foraging_df,palette='Pastel2',ax=ax[0])
sns.countplot(x='Eating',data=eating_df,palette='Pastel2',ax=ax[1])
sns.countplot(x='Running',data=running_df,palette='Pastel2',ax=ax[2])
sns.countplot(x='Climbing',data=climbing_df,palette='Pastel2',ax=ax[3])
sns.countplot(x='Chasing',data=chasing_df ,palette='Pastel2',ax=ax[4])
fig.show()

Comment: foraging_df = df.loc[df['Foraging'] == 'true']
eating_df = df.loc[df['Eating'] == 'true']
running_df = df.loc[df['Running'] == 'true']
climbing_df = df.loc[df['Climbing'] == 'true']
chasing_df = df.loc[df['Chasing'] == 'true']